# Наложение водяного знака на картинку

Tags: php, fileupload

Понадобилось наложить водяной знак на изображение, нашел в интернете такой код:

```html
<?php
  function can_upload($file){
 // если имя пустое, значит файл не выбран
    if($file['name'] == '')
  return 'Вы не выбрали файл.';
 
 /* если размер файла 0, значит его не пропустили настройки 
 сервера из-за того, что он слишком большой */
 if($file['size'] == 0)
  return 'Файл слишком большой.';
 
 // разбиваем имя файла по точке и получаем массив
 $getMime = explode('.', $file['name']);
 // нас интересует последний элемент массива - расширение
 $mime = strtolower(end($getMime));
 // объявим массив допустимых расширений
 $types = array('jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp', 'jpeg');
 
 // если расширение не входит в список допустимых - return
 if(!in_array($mime, $types))
  return 'Недопустимый тип файла.';
 
 return true;
  }

  function make_upload($file){
  // получаем полезные данные о картинке и водяном знаке
  $image_info = getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);
  $watermark_info = getimagesize('watermark.png');
  
  // определяем MIME-тип изображения, для выбора соответствующей функции
  $format = strtolower(substr($image_info['mime'], 
                                   strpos($image_info['mime'], '/') + 1));
  
  // определяем названия функция для создания и сохранения картинки
  $im_cr_func = "imagecreatefrom" . $format;
  $im_save_func = "image" . $format;
  
  // загружаем изображение в php
  $img = $im_cr_func($file['tmp_name']);
  
  // загружаем в php наш водяной знак
  $watermark = imagecreatefrompng('watermark.png');
  
  // определяем координаты левого верхнего угла водяного знака
  $pos_x = ($image_info[0] - $watermark_info[0]); 
  $pos_y = ($image_info[1] - $watermark_info[1]); 
  
  // помещаем водяной знак на изображение
  imagecopy($img, $watermark, $pos_x, $pos_y, 0, 0, $watermark_info[0], 
                    $watermark_info[1]);
 $getMime = explode('.', $file['name']);
 // нас интересует последний элемент массива - расширение
 $mime = strtolower(end($getMime));
 $name = time().".".$mime;
 
 $im_save_func($img, 'img/' . $name);
 echo $im_save_func;
}
```

```html
<?php
  include_once('functions.php')
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Загрузка изображений на сервер</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10485760">
      <input type="file" name="file">
      <input type="submit" value="Загрузить файл!">
    </form>
    <?php
    // если была произведена отправка формы
    if(isset($_FILES['file'])) {
      // проверяем, можно ли загружать изображение
      $check = can_upload($_FILES['file']);
    
      if($check === true){
        // загружаем изображение на сервер
        make_upload($_FILES['file']);
        echo "<strong>Файл успешно загружен!</strong>";
      }
      else{
        // выводим сообщение об ошибке
        echo "<strong>$check</strong>";  
      }
       echo $im_save_func;
    }
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Но проблема в том, что он накладывает водяной знак, когда загружаешь изображение на сервер, а что делать, если картинка уже лежит на сервере? Ознакомление с кодом показало, что во время работы многие данные код берет из `$_FILE`, когда картинка приходит на сервер. Поскольку изображение лежит уже на сервере, то ничего этого нет. Можете подсказать, как подредактировать код, чтобы он добавлял водяные знаки на уже загруженные изображения? Названия файлов, которые нужно отредактировать, я заранее знаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

За работу с изображением отвечает функция make_upload($file), где в качестве $file всегда передается $_FILE['file']. Сама функция использует только поля $file['tmp_name'] (как путь к файлу-источнику) и $file['name'] (как путь к результирующему файлу).

Вы можете ничего не менять и просто вызывать функцию таким образом:

```
$cfg = array(
    'tmp_name' => 'images/input.png', // Путь к исходному изображению
    'file' => 'images/output.png'     // Путь, по которому будет сохранено изображение с водным знаком 
);
make_upload($cfg);
```

Но я бы много чего сменил в коде примера, который вы нашли, он написан не лучшим образом для использования в реальных условиях.

Comment: Он почему-то не работает, видимо проблемы с какими-то элементами, потому, что после работы оно должно получить расширение файла, а оно его не получает + водный знак все равно не накладывается

Comment: Все, проблема решила, водный знак надо было PNG, а в массиве не хватало еще элемента с расширением. Спасибо за помощь!